# Empty content in custom MS Teams tab

Tags: teams-toolkit

I've created a custom Ms Teams tab using the Visual Studio Code extension. The content is very simple, it's only showing an iframe with a url.

hello.html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/custom.css" />
    <script
      src="https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.9.1/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-xnsUQ1tUqsrutBJl0vuf4/hufzLFWW8ZhGnhItfpQ0/BtWgM2uw6YT6BQ5YaKBSM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/teamsapp.js"></script>
    <title>Microsoft Teams Tab</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div>
      <div style="position:relative;padding-top:60%;">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S93nYy-Bxzo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
          style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is working ok when I debug the custom app (running on web), but doesn't work when I zip and load the app into Teams Desktop.

What could be the issue? My manifest is:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "${{TEAMS_APP_ID}}",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Company, Inc.",
        "websiteUrl": "www.google.com",
        "privacyUrl": "www.google.com",,
        "termsOfUseUrl": "www.google.com",
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "The Grid",
        "full": "The Grid"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "short desc",
        "full": "full desc"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [],
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "index0",
            "name": "Homepage",
            "contentUrl": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/tab",
            "websiteUrl": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/tab",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "personal",
                "groupChat"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "${{TAB_DOMAIN}}"
    ]
}
```

And the domain and endpoint are:

```
TAB_DOMAIN=localhost:53000
TAB_ENDPOINT=https://localhost:53000
```